# Insert street sed

Tags: linux, unix, sed

I want to insert the word STREET after all those who live in 2nd or 3rd so all 2nd or 3rd will be 2nd STREET and 3rd STREET. I'm using the sed command can someone please give me the correct syntax. I only want the first 9 lines

Thanks

Comment: Fairly basic use, what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following command should do the job

```
sed -r '1,9s/(2nd|3rd)/\1 STREET/g' file
```

This will preform search and replace in only first 9 lines.

**EDIT**

If you need only first 9 files from the file, use `head`

```
head -n 9 file | sed -r 's/(2nd|3rd)/\1 STREET/g'
```

Comment: I had a command similar to that but im just interested in only the first 9 lines. How do i modify it to just show the first 9 lines? Your command works beautifully however i just need the first 9 lines

Comment: You just need first 9 lines? I thought you want to replace in only first 9 lines

Comment: Yes just the first 9 lines i only want to show the first 9 lines. Sorry